# ASP.Net: Find parent control implementing interface T

Tags: c#, generics, interface, asp.net-4.0

I have this method which will give me the first parent control which is of the generic type T where T is a subtype of Control.

```
// Given a Control, find parent Control of T
public static T FindParent<T>(this Control ctrl) where T : Control
{
    var curParent = ctrl.Parent;
    while (curParent != null && !(curParent is T))
    {
        curParent = curParent.Parent;
    }
    return (T)curParent;
}
```

Now, however, I want to find a parent control which implements an interface T. When I remove the `where T : Control` clause from the method, the `return (T)curParent` line gives the compilation error `Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case since `curParent` is typed as a `Control` (from `ctrl.Parent`), no, the *compiler* doesn't know how to cast/convert a `Control` to some arbitrary generic type `T`. However, since you know at *runtime* that the type is compatible, you can easily get around it by first casting to `object`:

```
public static T FindParent<T>(this Control ctrl)
{
    var curParent = ctrl.Parent;
    while (curParent != null && !(curParent is T))
    {
        curParent = curParent.Parent;
    }
    return (T)(object)curParent;
}
```

In this case, the compiler can't complain and it will just have to trust that you know what you're doing at runtime, which we do in this case because of the `curParent is T` checking.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Also this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic5) provides some insight under **Generics and Casting**